# Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 8 (Titanium)

Tags: android

I'm using Titanium Studio, build: 3.2.1
And I want to launch my app with the emulator but when I do that I receive this error: [ERROR] Application Installer abnormal process termination. Process exit value was 8
does someone know how I can fix this?

I'm using windows 8, 64 bit and have all android sdk's installed.

Answer (score 0):

I've the exact phenomenon with ubuntu13.10. I found this bug https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-16169 .
However, the last titanium SDK seems to be build: 3.2.1.201402041146, which doesn't contains the fix.